# Jenkins escaping $ in credential secret file in json format

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a pipeline which uses a secret file using credential plugin, the file in json format as below. The pipeline simply copies the file to a target machine where we have an ansible playbook gets triggered locally.

```
{ "key" : "value$$" }
```

But when it comes to execution, the copied secret file on the local machine, we can only see as below.

```
{ "key" : "value$" }
```

Basically one $ seems to be escaping. we tried "'value$$'" and "value$$$$" but that didnt help.

Jenkins Pipeline:

```
environment {
        def values = "${SITE_AGENT}".split('-')
        credentialsId = "security-keys-${values[-2]}-${values[-1]}"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Initialise') {
            steps {
            // Make the build name something meaningful
                buildName "${NODE_NAME}-${BUILD_USER_ID}-#${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                buildDescription "Runing ${Tag_Name} in ${SITE_AGENT}"
            }
        }
        stage('Run deployment.yml') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([
                    usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'git-deploy-token', passwordVariable: 'git_pass', usernameVariable: 'git_user'), file(credentialsId: "${credentialsId}", variable: 'secret_file')
                ]) {
                    ansiblePlaybook(
                        colorized: true,
                        playbook: '$WORKSPACE/playbook/deployment.yml',
                        extraVars: [
                            tag_name:"${Tag_Name}",
                            git_url:"${Git_Project}",
                            deploy:"${Deploy_Playbook}",
                            git_user:"${git_user}",
                            git_pass:"${git_pass}",
                            secret_file:[value:readFile(secret_file), hidden:true]
                        ]
                    )
```

Comment: show us pipeline stage.